# Wrong Coordinates on QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have just started using QGIS for an assignment. I'm just new on that so I will try to explain what my question is.
I have added a map  of Vic Australia from near map. I used the GDA94/ MGA zone 55 for CRS. I then added an OpenStreetMap map (using the same CRS) which is aligned ok. On the next step, I'm trying to add some vectors (shapefile) I have download from a government site. However, when I add the vectors, their coordinates are wrong (although I use the same CRS). The location from these vectors is correct (you can see the features) but they are aligned.

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have added OpenStreetMap, the QGIS changes its map coordinate system to EPSG:3857. Any layers added later will be converted onfly to the EPSG: 3857.  So the coordinates shoud have been referring to EPSG: 3857 after adding vector layers on the QGIS Map.

Comment: Thank you so much! The CRS had changed after the OpenStreetMap Added and everything was out of place.